# Cloning a private repo with Composer in Docker (at runtime)

Tags: git, docker, composer-php, ssh-agent

I am trying to install PHP packages using Composer, via the [Composer Docker image](https://hub.docker.com/_/composer). Some of those packages are in private git repos, so authentication is needed.

The SSH agent approach listed in the Docker image docs is not working for unknown reasons.

```
eval $(ssh-agent); docker run --rm --interactive --tty \
    --volume $PWD:/app --user $(id -u):$(id -g) \
    --volume ${COMPOSER_HOME:-$HOME/.composer}:/tmp \
    --volume $SSH_AUTH_SOCK:/ssh-auth.sock --env SSH_AUTH_SOCK=/ssh-auth.sock \
    composer install --optimize-autoloader
```

The error I get is

> Cloning failed using an ssh key for authentication, enter your GitHub
> credentials to access private repos Head to
> https://github.com/settings/tokens/new?scopes=repo&description=Composer+on+fe2cdd1a88f1+2021-05-04+1339
> to retrieve a token. It will be stored in "/tmp/auth.json" for future
> use by Composer.

The applicable private key has been added to ssh-agent on my host, and I can clone the private repos there without any issues.

I've looked through many *similar* questions but did not find anything that leads to the repo being cloned.

Comment: That `--volume $SSH_AUTH_SOCK:/ssh-auth.sock` trick is interesting. Does it work? (Maybe not, based on the results you saw.) Where did it come from?

Comment: @torek straight from the image's [documentation](https://hub.docker.com/_/composer).

Comment: @yivi: also interesting, including the fact that it requires specific Docker versions for specific OSes. :-)

Comment: What have you tried to debug the problem? If you are facing "unknown reasons", I doubt that this is a problem of Composer itself

Comment: I am unsure how to debug further.